# Is my SSD dead? 3 year old laptop will not boot into Windows 10 or safe mode

Tags: ssd

My 3 year old Dell XPS 15 9560 laptop will not boot into Windows 10 or safe modes.

UEFI and BIOS list the SSD (as follows) and Dell ePSA does not detect any errors/problems with any part of the system including the hard drive, but Automatic Repair fails and diskpart lists no disks which were run from a bootable Windows 10 USB flash drive.

```
UEFI > General > Boot Sequence:
Boot Sequence : UEFI: THNSN5256GPUK NVMe Toshiba 256gb Partition 1

UEFI > General > System Info:
Device Info > Primary Hard Drive : {none}
Device Info > m.2 PCIe SSD-0 : 278B32AUKSGU (which matches hard drive BIOS code)
```

I removed the back of the laptop, re-seated the SSD, cleaned the fans and put it back together and restarted it and nothing changed from the above.

**Is my SSD dead?**

Comment: First backup all your data by putting the SSD into another computer or using USB HDD enclosure. If the backup succeed then your SSD should not be dead. Then reinstall Windows on a clean SSD by removing all old partitions first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SATA1 hard drive not seen by BIOS anymore](https://superuser.com/questions/695510/sata1-hard-drive-not-seen-by-bios-anymore)